# Using JNI parameters as reference compared to coping them

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have jni function which accepts a string via GetStringUTFChars from JAVA code and stores it in c++ data structure. 
IIUC the string will not be deleted as long ReleaseStringUTFChars will not be called even after the jni function exited. My question is- is it OK that the c++ code will use this string (or char *) as is instead of coping it to a new one? in the aspect of performance does this approach is better than copy the string and releasing it? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that you're planning to do exactly. If you don't (ever) call `ReleaseStringUTFChars` you will most likely end up leaking memory (might depend on the exact VM; on Android you'd leak because `ReleaseStringUTFChars` calls `delete[]`). If you do call `ReleaseStringUTFChars` and keep using the same `const char*` you'll have a use-after-free which has undefined behaviour.

Comment: If I will not call ReleaseStringUTFChars at all but rather release the memory in c++ program by myself when I end using the string that wouldn't be ok? tnx

Comment: It won't necessarily be ok, unless you're targeting only a specific version of a specific VM, and you're familiar with that VM's implementation details. Calling `free` on memory allocated with `new[]` (or `delete[]` on memory allocated with `malloc`) could lead to problems. Seems better to me to either 1) copy the string data (e.g. by creating a `std::string` from it), or 2) Wrap the `const char*` in some object that calls `ReleaseStringUTFChars` in its destructor.